# Getting error while installing android studio for linux 64 bit machine

Tags: dpkg, java, android

I got an error while installing Android Studio and this is the error message: I used this link to install android studio https://developer.android.com/studio/install

I'm getting below error message.

```
Errors were encountered while processing: 
oracle-java11-installer-local
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Error image snapshot:

[image]

Can someone please help. Thanks in advance

Comment: Install Android Studio from the Ubuntu Software Center. It would be much easier

Answer (score 0):

Android Studio doesn't require separate installation of Java Development Kit. I don't think so you have followed same procedure as stated on Android Studio website https://developer.android.com/studio/install

1. Download the android studio `android-studio-ide-192.6392135-linux.tar.gz` and extract it and move it to `/opt` directory.
2. Install these dependencies `sudo apt-get install libc6:i386 libncurses5:i386 libstdc++6:i386 lib32z1 libbz2-1.0:i386`
3. Navigate to `/opt/android-studio/` and execute `studio.sh`.
4. The installation wizard will be started. When installation will be finished you can create a `Shortcut` to it by clicking `Tools > Create Desktop Entry`